# Class confusion in Python with the getattr

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, self, getattr

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11838075/when-a-function-in-a-class-returns-a-value-where-is-it-returned-to) . However, the responses didn't really help me grasp how some parts of the program worked. The program is as follows:

```
from sys import exit
from random import randint

class Game(object):

    def __init__(self, start):
        self.pie = [ 'pie test']

        self.start = start

    def play(self):
        next_room_name = self.start
        while True:
            print "\n--------"
            room = getattr(self, next_room_name)
            next_room_name = room()

    def rooom(self):
        print "Test worked. good job"
        return "piez"

    def piez(self):
        print "pie room"
        exit(1)


a_game = Game("rooom")
a_game.play()
```

The first question is how is the following working?

```
def play(self):
        next_room_name = self.start

        while True:
            print "\n--------"
            room = getattr(self, next_room_name)
            next_room_name = room()
```

I know that somehow the following is generating the room name so the program can go to where it needs to. I'm just not seeing how it is happening.

My second question is:

```
self.start = start
```

I sort of understand self.pie is doing. But I'm not sure what self.start = start is suppose to accomplish. Thanks again for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that you have some class like this:

```
class DummyClass(object):

    awesome = True

    def not_awesome(self):
        self.awesome=False
```

Using getattr on this is exactly equivalent to using the dot syntax, e.g.

```
dumb = DummyClass()
print getattr(dummy, "awesome") # True
print dummy.awesome # True
```

You can use this with methods too:

```
dumb = DummyClass()
no_more_awesome = getattr(dummy, "not_awesome") # returns the not_awesome method of dummy
print dummy.awesome # True
no_more_awesome()
print dummy.awesome # False
```

So, in the code snippet you posted, the `getattr(self, next_room_name)` gets the method with name `next_room_name` and returns the function (bound to self) to be called. You use a variable instead of dot syntax here because you don't know the name in advance.  Consider the following two snippets to get this (a bit confusing with overlaps...sorry):

```
dummy = DummyClass()
awesome = "not_awesome"
print dummy.awesome # True
print getattr(dummy, awesome) # string with something like <bound method ... >
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all: object initialization. When `Game("rooom")` is called, the string `"rooom"` is bound to the parameter `start` of `__init__`. The statement `this.start = start` simply stores the string `"rooom"` in the internal object dictionary, accessible through `this.start`.

Then `play()` method is called: the usage of `getattr` in this context defines a pattern called [Pluggable Selector](https://www.google.it/search?q=pluggable%20selector&sugexp=chrome,mod=6&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). In other words, rather than explicitly stating which method to call, the name of the method is stored is a variable (`next_room_name` in this case).

The first method to be called is `rooom` because the local variable `next_room_name` (local to the scope of the method `play`) is initialized to `self.start` before the while loop.

The return value of the method call is used to update the `next_room_name` variable, therefore after `rooom` executes, the value becomes `"piez"`. Hence, the next method to be called is going to be `piez`.

Finally, when `piez` executes, a call to `exit(1)` is made, therefore the interpreter is terminated, with no further execution of code. The reason why no more code executes, in this case, is that `sys.exit` raises a `SystemExit` exception (see [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.exit)), which is not caught anywhere.